# Edit host file to redirect domains, Hackxor?

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, security, web-application

I am playing with a vulnerable web application game called Hackxor. The installation [instruction](http://hackxor.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/index.pl) says...

"*Configure your hosts file (/etc/hosts on linux) to redirect the following domains to the IP of hackxor: wraithmail, wraithbox, cloaknet, GGHB, hub71, utrack."*

As you can see there's no specific domain(.com,.net) is given. should i just add the *x.x.x.x http://wraithmail* into hosts file? which does not work, neither does *wraithmail.com*. what am i doing wrong. I have never edited the hosts file and not a genius of vitualbox networking.
I am using windows 7 as host and hackxor is installed as vm in vbox.

Comment: So from what you are saying and from what I can get from the instructions it looks like you would take the IP you login to. Which they show a possibility of 172.16.93.129 is the possible login ip. So using that as an example would me you would put it in like so. You would put it like this `172.16.93.129 www.wraithmail.com`

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Yes kind of, but in my case the vm assigned different IP than *172.16.93.129*. I did follow *x.x.x.x. www.wraithmail.com* as you mentioned but i get DNS server error while accessing *http://wraithmail:8080* , which simply means i am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things first:

1. Domain names are not URLs; they're only *part of* an URL (for example, the URL `https://superuser.com/questions/1075966/` has the domain `superuser.com`).

   So the `http://` has no place in `/etc/hosts`.
2. Domains are looked up exactly as written. While the OS *might* add the system domain name at the end, it isn't going to add or remove components like `www` at random. In other words:

   `wraithmail` and `wraithmail.com` are not the same thing.
    `wraithmail` and `www.wraithmail.com` are not the same thing.
    `wraithmail.com` and `www.wraithmail.com` are not the same thing.

   (However, they're case-insensitive; `GGHB` and `gghb` *are* the same thing.)

Therefore, if your VM's IP address is `172.16.93.129`, then the correct entries would be:

```
172.16.93.129 wraithmail wraithbox cloaknet GGHB hub71 utrack
```

Or:

```
172.16.93.129 wraithmail
172.16.93.129 wraithbox
172.16.93.129 cloaknet
172.16.93.129 GGHB
172.16.93.129 hub71
172.16.93.129 utrack
```

Comment: How come 'website.com' and 'www.website.com' are not the same thing?

Comment: Um. Why _would_ they be the same thing? They're different names. There's nothing magic about `www` that would make it "the same" while other subdomains aren't. (In fact I'm pretty sure the earliest websites used a subdomain precisely _because_ it was separarate from the base domain.)

Comment: Very well, consider the above scenario where i have added `172.16.93.129 wraithmail wraithbox cloaknet GGHB hub71 utrack` into the hosts file as you recommended and its working fine while accessing `http://wraithmail:8080`. Can you please differentiate on a technical level what happens when I try to access
``

Comment: Cloud you please elaborate on a technical level? How is it different? when i access `wraithmail:8080` it works fine and i am able to pick the web resource. I know that `x.x.x.x:port_number` or `website:port_number` is a socket. whats the difference/ or what would happen if I try

`http://website.com`
`www.website.com`
`website.com`

You don't have take this wraithmail scenario I am just trying to understand(technically) what happens when one access above resource.

Comment: DNS is the system that translates human-readable names (`wraithmail`) into IP addresses.  After that step is done, then your computer establishes a connection to a certain port on the machine located at that address.  There is no analogous lookup for port numbers to determine different machines to connect to, because that's a different spec :) .